# Stop Recording when no one speaks

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

good afternoon,

I have a Windows application which start recording on pressing start button and stops recording on stop button click and stops recording when we unplug the microphone its working fine, but my new requirement is when i press start button the recording starts and if I do not speak for few minutes the recording should stop. I am unable google this question.
I am stuck up with this problem can anyone help me?

here is the sample code for start and stop recording

```
uint hr = MFRecWrapper.StartRecording(microPhoneName.Trim(), this.fileName.Trim(), this.bitSamplingBitrate, this.avgBytesWrittenPerSecond, this.Handle);
uint hr = MFRecWrapper.StopRecording();
```

Thank you in advance.. :)

Comment: You would need to analyze the audio as you are recording. It looks like you are using a custom wrapper-class to access the microphone. Are you able to use that class to extract the recorded audio while you are recording? (or even better, only extract the part you need to analyze)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to analyze your audio input stream. There are some simple techniques to do this, and there are some more advanced.

As a starter, you could simply fix a loudness threshold. If your input loudness is below that for a given time, stop recording.
A more advanced and IMHO better approach would be to calculate the SNR of your input signal and use this as your criterion.

To conclude: this is a quite difficult task. The open source app [Mumble](http://mumble.sourceforge.net) has some of this functionality implemented. I think it's a good idea to start getting your inspiration there.